# How to make the page load an error page after the tomcat session timeout?

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I need to provide the user with error page after the tomcat session time out. So to handle this is created a filter and added some logic to detect this and after that i am saying go to the error page.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    M_log.debug("startFilter");
    HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest)arg0;
    HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse)arg1;
    String title = request.getParameter("context_title");
    TcSessionData tcSession = (TcSessionData) request.getSession.getAttribute("TcSessionData");
    if((title!=null && tcSession==null) || (title==null && tcSession!=null) ){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }else if(title==null && tcSession==null) {
        //response.sendRedirect("/error/error.jsp");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/error/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }


}
```

After session times out i see that it is going to right "if" logic and it is not forwarding/redirecting to my error.jsp. It is giving a 404 error. I tried both redirect and forward of the page but no success.I tired both absolute and relative path for the error.jsp page still i see 404 error saying that it can't find the error.jsp page. I also tried to put the error.jsp various location under `webapps` Directory still no luck

My application has only one page called root.jsp. when session time out the application will always be root.jsp and after timeout i wrote to go to error.jsp.

Here is my `web.xml`

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CheckSessionExpirationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>lti.google.CheckSessionExpirationFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CheckSessionExpirationFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>GoogleDriveLti</servlet-name>
 </filter-mapping>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>GoogleDriveLti</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>lti.google.GoogleLtiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GoogleDriveLti</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout> <!-- in minutes -->
  </session-config>
```

Here is my Folder structure

[image]

Comment: A root application goes under `webapps/ROOT` not right under webapps. You shouldn't have your WEB-INF right under webapps.

Comment: Use response.sendRedirect("/error/error.jsp"); and Post your address bar full URL

Comment: @Tusar: This is URL. http://localhost:8080/google-drive-lti/service. i am using response.sendRedirect("/error/error.jsp");but still no luck

Comment: @developerwjk: What is the problem of having WEB-INF under the webapps directory?

Comment: @developerwjk: A root application goes under webapps/ROOT not right under webapps? What do you mean by that? i am confused.

Comment: @developerwjk: I tried to move the root.jsp file under webapps/root.jsp. It did not made a difference i see the same error as before.

Comment: webapps/ROOT/ as in a folder named ROOT, not a JSP named root.jsp

Comment: Install Tomcat fresh and you'll see what I mean. They have a folder named ROOT. URLs like `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp` the index.jsp is in webapps/ROOT not just under webapps. And its WEB-INF isn't dangling in webapps, but is in webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/

Comment: @pushya I mean the page which gives 404 error. ie: something localhost:8080/g../error/error.jsp (I need this link- to check whether it is valid path)

Comment: @Tusar: http://localhost:8080/error/error.jsp this is the URL the browser try to redirect and the Actual URL is the application is http://localhost:8080/google-drive-lti/service. I tired http://localhost:8080/google-drive-lti/service/error/error.jsp with this too it did not work and redirection went in to infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

```
localhost:8080/error/error.jsp
```

Here you can see the Context name is not present in the url.

Try (removing '/')

```
 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/error/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

OR

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("error/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I tired this too request.getSession().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view/error.jsp").forward(request, response); still not working

Comment: Just create a simple servlet and forward/redirect from that. OR send your source code (required files only). trytusar@gmail.com